# pandas.json_normalize sending Not Implemented Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have below line in my data pipeline code which takes json array and normalizes it using pandas.json_normalize

```
df = pd.json_normalize(reviews, sep='_')
```

Now when reviews is getting null or None, it has suddenly started failing. What should be done here?

I tried writing all the data that review receives in a for loop, and from that I understood, this failure occurs only when review receives null

Answer (score 0):

Which version of pandas are you using?

If you get the error `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has oo attribute 'json_normalize'` after inserting `from pandas import json_normalize` it may be due to the version you are using.

You have to downgrade the pandas to the version before **1.0.3**. Since you need to import the json_normalize module from the pandas package directly into newer versions from pandas, import json_normalize instead.

After that you can try out something like:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data = { "xy": ["1","2","3"] }
json = json_normalize(data)
```